# Error using syntax fitcnb() MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bayesian, naivebayes

I have variable (type table) in matlab:

[image]

and I'm using `fitcnb` for training naive bayes. I execute code:

```
Mdl = fitcnb(data,'class')
```

But I get an error :

> Error using classreg.learning.FullClassificationRegressionModel.prepareDataCR (line 129) X must be a numeric matrix.
>
> Error in classreg.learning.classif.FullClassificationModel.prepareData (line 455) [X,Y,W,dataSummary] = ...
>
> Error in classreg.learning.FitTemplate/fit (line 205 [X,Y,dataPrepOut{1:this.NDataPrepOut}] = ...
>
> Error in ClassificationNaiveBayes.fit (line 127) this = fit(temp,X,Y);
>
> Error in fitcnb (line 219) this = ClassificationNaiveBayes.fit(X,Y,varargin{:});

`fitcnb` call's syntax is correct

```
Mdl = fitcnb(tbl,ResponseVarName)
```

But why I get an error ?

Comment: I think why you get the error is described in the error log: `Error using classreg.learning.FullClassificationRegressionModel.prepareDataCR (line 129) X must be a numeric matrix.` which means X is not a numeric matrix can you tell what does `X` contains ?

Comment: The variable x has been numerically [http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtlm9.png]